# Accessibility (ADA) coding challenge on java script drop-down control (Multi select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

While implementing accessibility for a multi select drop down control I faced a problem, When the user focus on the drop down using ctr+ up/down arrows, user can change the focus of option. I am not able to find the jQuery syntax to locate the focused option. Any helps? Otherwise, can anyone help with a fully functional jQuery control with ADA functionalities?

```
<select id="cars" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option enter code here>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by 'locate the focused option'. Are you looking for the syntax to find out which item is currently selected (`$('#id').val()` would give you 'volvo' etc.) or do you need something else as you mention ADA compliance and feel I am missing the point of what you require.

Comment: We can select an item via a mouse click and we can move up/down using Ctrl+/-. If I move Ctrl+ and the current focus can be at Opel. This is not a selection, but just a focus. How to identify that current focus using javascript?

Comment: I'm skeptical as to whether this can actually be accomplished using the standard HTML `select` and `option` elements. You may need to find a replacement JS solution. I haven't found that the `option` elements can be manipulated using either the `:focus` or `:selected` jQuery selectors. I can hook into the fully-selected elements just fine, but the focused `option` elements cannot even be targeted with CSS.